# How to use guard correctly?

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]Hello, I have a condition, if the variables are empty, to show a error message, it works, but after i press for a second time on the button, the button is working even if the variable are still empty.

This is the condition :

```
    guard !verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompleteFirstName.isEmpty,
              !verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompleteLastName.isEmpty,
              !verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompletePhoneNumber.isEmpty,
              !verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompleteDeliveryAddress.isEmpty else {

            verifyFieldViewModel.promptFirstName = "First Name is Empty"
            verifyFieldViewModel.promptLastName = "Last Name is Empty"
            verifyFieldViewModel.promptPhoneNumber = "Phone Number is Empty"
            verifyFieldViewModel.promptDeliveryAddress = "Address is Empty"
                  return

              }
```

Comment: There is clearly something happening somewhere else in your code because the posted code can not be the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to do the condition check validation ignorer to maintain clean and readable code:

```
    func isAllFieldsEmpty() -> Bool {
        return verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompleteFirstName.isEmpty && verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompleteLastName.isEmpty && verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompletePhoneNumber.isEmpty && verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpCompleteDeliveryAddress.isEmpty
    }
```

Using Guard statement:

```
    guard isAllFieldsEmpty() else {
        return
    }
    verifyFieldViewModel.promptFirstName = "First Name is Empty"
    verifyFieldViewModel.promptLastName = "Last Name is Empty"
    verifyFieldViewModel.promptPhoneNumber = "Phone Number is Empty"
    verifyFieldViewModel.promptDeliveryAddress = "Address is Empty"
```

Using If statement:

```
 if isAllFieldsEmpty()  {
        verifyFieldViewModel.promptFirstName = "First Name is Empty"
        verifyFieldViewModel.promptLastName = "Last Name is Empty"
        verifyFieldViewModel.promptPhoneNumber = "Phone Number is Empty"
        verifyFieldViewModel.promptDeliveryAddress = "Address is Empty"
    }
```